# Adding onClick function to items in ActionBar (Android)

Tags: java, android

I have created a dropdown list in my android action bar with 2 items inside it. I want to be able to add onClick functions to these 2 items so that I can make them open another activity. Below is the xml code where I set up one of the items in the dropdown list:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:title="@string/home"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

I then have the ActionBar.java class:

```
public class ActionBar extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_home:
            Intent i = new Intent(ActionBar.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
}
```

Whenever I click this 'action_home' item in my actionbar nothing happens, but I need it to open my homepage (MainActivity).

I also have the following code in all of my activities java classes in order to make the actionbar appear:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Click handle here.

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        // Do your code
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
          // Do your code
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Roadies I have tried to put my code in to the format you've suggested. I don't get any errors now, but when the button's clicked it still doesn't function how I want it to (question updated). Thanks for the response!

Comment: Done! Think that's all relevant code included now, thanks